# Lambda boto3 python - error - ClientError: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Not Found

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a Lambda function `Lambda1` that runs Transcribe on a file, saves it to an s3 bucket and returns a dictionary (which has the location of the srt file created) that is passed out of one Lambda1 and to Lambda2 as a destination.

Lambda2 then is supposed to form a download object so I can then run a process on this .srt file to convert it to another type of file.

**Data**

```
return {
        'TranscriptionJobName': response['TranscriptionJob']['TranscriptionJobName'],
        'BucketDestination': destination_bucket_name,
        'ObjectKey': job_name+'.srt'
        
    }
```

A sample of this output looks like this, I have shortened it to show the necessary items.

```
{'responsePayload': {'TranscriptionJobName': 'test_short49', 'BucketDestination': 'bucket-1', 'ObjectKey': 'test_short49.srt'}}
```

The lambda2 then receives this information and I parse it with the following code
**Lambda2 Code**

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    source_bucket_name = event['responsePayload']['BucketDestination']
    file_name = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['responsePayload']['ObjectKey'])
    destination_bucket_name = 'bucket-1'

    # Download the source file from S3
    source_object = s3.Object(source_bucket_name, file_name)
    print(f'The source object is {source_object}')
    source_file = '/tmp/source.srt'
    source_object.download_file(source_file)
```

I am getting an error on the last line of the code.

```
[ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Not Found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 32, in lambda_handler
    source_object.download_file(source_file)
  File "/var/runtime/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 359, in object_download_file
    return self.meta.client.download_file(
  File "/var/runtime/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 190, in download_file
    return transfer.download_file(
  File "/var/runtime/boto3/s3/transfer.py", line 326, in download_file
    future.result()
  File "/var/runtime/s3transfer/futures.py", line 103, in result
    return self._coordinator.result()
  File "/var/runtime/s3transfer/futures.py", line 266, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/var/runtime/s3transfer/tasks.py", line 269, in _main
    self._submit(transfer_future=transfer_future, **kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/s3transfer/download.py", line 354, in _submit
    response = client.head_object(
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 530, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 960, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
```

I have successfully gotten the code to run if I use the .srt file as an S3 trigger.  I have printed out the results to see if I have formed something incorrectly.  No matter how I form my `source_object`, I get an error if I pass the information using the Lambda1 function.

I am wondering if it could be that the SRT file created from Transcribe has not made it into the S3 bucket before Lambda2 starts looking for it?

Comment: If you add some debugging code to print the contents of `file_name`, does it look correct (including the Full Path to the object)?

Comment: How are you waiting for the transcription job to finish?

Comment: Thank you John, I think the debugging makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Hi Anon, I really am not waiting or at least finding out if it is completed.  There is a `GetTranscriptionJob` that I could use to check to see if it completes.

Comment: As I think about it, It may make sense to just let the s3 caption file be the trigger for the next Lambda.  That way, I am not staying in a Lambda function unnecessarily longer than needed.

Comment: If you're not waiting for it to complete, then it follows that the object might not be in S3 yet.  You either need to check with `['TranscriptionJob']['TranscriptionJobStatus']` with some frequency to see when it toggles to `COMPLETED`, or handle the 404 errors till the object exists.